# Unable to disable daemon using Systemd

Tags: ubuntu, boot, systemd, mpd

I've tried disabling MPD (Music Player Daemon) using Systemd:

```
sudo systemctl disable mpd

sudo systemctl status mpd
mpd.service - Music Player Daemon
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

But MPD runs at every boot regardless.

```
ps aux | grep mpd

user   1691  0.1  0.8 995424 33108 ?        Ssl  09:07   0:00 mpd
user   2154  0.0  0.0  14216  2464 pts/5    S+   09:17   0:00 grep --color=auto mpd
```

How can I disable MPD from running at boot?

Comment: MPD is running as your user - does is get started from a user session by any chance (systemctl --user status mpd)?

Comment: @Wieland I suspected this too earlier. But `systemctl --user status mpd` produces
    
    Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
    Active: inactive (dead)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `dpkg -L mpd` to see what files got installed by the package you should find amongst others

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/mpd.service
/usr/lib/systemd/system/mpd.socket
```

This means that systemd has been configured by mpd to create a socket that then launches the service whenever it is opened. When you `disable mpd` this is a shorthand for disabling `mpd.service`. You need to also disable the socket explicitly with

```
sudo systemctl disable mpd.socket
```

Update: it appears to be unrelated to systemd. Depending on your window manager, you may have a file in your own directory `~/.config/autostart/` that starts mpd, or try finding a configuration by going through your menus in the approximate order: System -> Preferences -> Sessions -> Startup Programs.

Finally, it appeared in gnome-session-properties as something to disable.